# How To Fire button Click event From BootStrap SliderStop

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

How do I make bootstrap `slider` `slideStop` event to get the `slider` value assign the `slider` value to a label control then fire a button click.

aspx

```
 <input id="ex13"   type="text" data-slider-selection = "after" data-slider-step="200" data-slider-ticks="[1000, 4000, 8000]" data-slider-ticks-snap-bounds="30" data-slider-ticks-labels='["N1K", "N4K", "N8K"]'/>
```

JS

```
$("#ex13").slider().on('slideStop',function(ev){
document.getElementById('<%=lblpricecode.ClientID%>').data("#ex13").val(ev.value)});
fuction()
{
document.getElementById('<%=btnCallPriceSearchQry.ClientID%>').click();
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use:

```
$('#<%=btnCallPriceSearchQry.ClientID%>>').trigger('click');
```

The problem in your code is: the function to trigger the click has no name!

So you can add a name to your function like:

```
        fuction triggerClick()
        {
            document.getElementById('').click();
        }
```

Declare such a function before calling it or move the code directly  inside  your event handler:

```
        $("#ex13").slider().on('slideStop',function(ev){
            document.getElementById('').data("#ex13").val(ev.value);
            document.getElementById('').click();
        });
```

With the function the code will be:

```
        fuction triggerClick()
        {
            document.getElementById('').click();
        }

        $("#ex13").slider().on('slideStop',function(ev){
            document.getElementById('').data("#ex13").val(ev.value);
            triggerClick();
        });
```

When you declare a function without a name pay atention to the errors you get in the browser console: Uncaught ReferenceError: fuction is not defined.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use jquery to get an element by id
The trigger function will do this job.
See: **http://api.jquery.com/trigger/**

Put all the code in the event function.
See example below

```
$("#ex13").slider().on('slideStop',function(ev){
    $('#<%=lblpricecode.ClientID%>').data("#ex13").val(ev.value);
    $('#<%=btnCallPriceSearchQry.ClientID%>').trigger("click");
});
```

Comment: i am still having same probs; First; when I move the slider from pointA to PointB, i was expecting btnCallPriceSearchQry to trigger at that point, that is not happening, secondly; I declared a string variable TEST and assign it to lblpricecode.text under  btnCallPriceSearchQry_click;  I was expecting TEST to now have the value of the slider but TEST is empty ie TEST=" ". Please help or is my logic wrong

Comment: still No progress, it looks like the slideStop event is not firing at all.

Comment: Try using this instead for simulating an click: `$(#'<%=btnCallPriceSearchQry.ClientID%>')[0].click();`

Comment: I think we are getting closer; when i comment out this line: $('#<%=lblpricecode.ClientId%>').data("#ex13").val(ev.value); the trigger fires, what could be wrong with this line, i need this value for a query string

Answer (score 0):

Here is how i finally sorted it

```
$("#ex13").slider().on('slideStop',function(ev){var mypriceinput=document.getElementById("<%=PriceString.ClientId%>");
mypriceinput.value=(ev.value);
document.getElementById("<%=btnCallPriceSearchQry.ClientId%>").click();
});
```

Meanwhile thanks to all